# Two arguments for Process in C#

Tags: c#

How to put two arguments into the Argument property, And after run process this arguments should be read by the bat file.
I mean that :
 if I write

```
            var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "batosql.bat",
                **Arguments = serverNameTextBox+ " " + pathToSql,**
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                ErrorDialog = true,
                WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(".")
            }
        };
```

after start process

```
proc.Start();
```

these arguments should be put into the bat file

```
osql -E -S %1 -i %2
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: it work correct for one argument but I have a problems when counts of arguments increase to more than one. In this question I put example with two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to wrap the arguments in quotation marks, if they contain spaces or other special characters.

```
Arguments = "\"" + serverNameTextBox + "\" \"" + pathToSql + "\"",
```